# How to import these file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

> How to import these file in mongodb, here is my json file

```
        [{
        "_id": ObjectId(),
        "title": "How long  running and abdominal excersises?",
        "author": {
            "userid": ObjectId(),
            "name": "clark Loews",
        },
        "postdatetime": Date(),
    },
{
        "_id": ObjectId(),
        "title": "How long will it take me to lose 15-20 pounds with running and abdominal excersises?",
        "author": {
            "userid": ObjectId(),
            "name": "Bart Loews",
        },
        "postdatetime": Date(),
    }
]
```

> It give me this error:-**Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: expected 1 argument to ObjectId constructor, but 0 received**

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... You'll need actual data to import. Having the `ObjectId()` and `Date()` functions in a `json` file will not work. How would the `userid` fields actually match anything in your database?

Note that you can skip the `_id` field when importing and MongoDB will create unique values for you, but the other fields in your document will need to be explicit.

Comment: what to do if i want to auto generated the user id and date